# Need to calculate payroll for a few employees in SQL (across two tables)

Tags: sql, sql-server

So far I have

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    ed.FirstName,
    ed.LastName,
    ed.Salary
FROM EmployeeData ed
INNER JOIN JobTitle jt
    ON ed.JobID = jt.JobID
    AND jt.ExemptNonExemptStatus = 'Exempt'
ORDER BY ed.Salary
```

However, I'm uncertain as to what is left to add the salaries together. I imagine a SUM function is in order, but every time I try something - it errors out. Can anyone help?

Comment: you want the SUM(salary) for all whose status is Exempt ?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please read the [help] and [ask] sections.

Comment: Question is not clear to me. Please add information.

Comment: Wait, what? If you sum the salaries together, which first name and last name do you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 SELECT 
        ed.FirstName,
        ed.LastName,
        SUM(ed.Salary) as SalaryPerEmployee
    FROM EmployeeData ed
    INNER JOIN JobTitle jt ON ed.JobID = jt.JobID
                           AND jt.ExemptNonExemptStatus = 'Exempt'
    GROUP BY ed.FirstName,  ed.LastName,
    ORDER BY SalaryPerEmployee;
```

Comment: [Please don't use `ORDER BY n`, it's way too brittle](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/06/bad-habits-to-kick-order-by-ordinal.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you just want a sum of all of the exempt employees, and don't need to have first name and last name in the result set (which I don't even know which one(s) you would list):

```
SELECT Salary = SUM(ed.Salary)
FROM dbo.EmployeeData AS ed
WHERE EXISTS
(
  SELECT 1 FROM dbo.JobTitle
    WHERE JobID = ed.JobID 
    AND ExemptNonExemptStatus = 'Exempt'
);
```